# Safari can't open… because the server unexpectedly dropped connection error

Tags: connection, mamp, osx-yosemite

Ever since I started using Yosemite and MAMP 3.0.7.3, I often receive the following error:

`Safari can't open the page "localhost:8888/whatever-page-i-am-navigating-to" because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.`

MAMP's ports are set to default:
`Apache: 8888` 
`Nginx: 7888`
`MySQL: 8889`

I tried setting Web & MySQL ports to 80 & 3306 but I get the following alert:
`ERROR
There is a problem with the server ports. Each server must be assigned a unique port. Please check your configuration.`

This occurs sporadically and my search on Google reveals no solution to this, only ongoing discussions.

I never get this error when I was working on OS 10.5.8 and the MAMP's version for that OS (don't remember what it was).

I highly appreciate any pointers to solving this error.

Thank you very much!
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured this out, but a few quick thoughts:

- When you click the settings to "Set Web & MySQL ports to 80 and 3306", it will reset both Apache and Nginx to 80. I was getting the same "Each server...unique port" error, but when I changed Nginx to a different port number, it resolved.
- I did, however, end up leaving Apache set up on port 8888. But I have MySQL on port 3306.
- Another thing I noticed in my install was that I was unable to get MySQL to connect after making some of these changes. I was able to resolve that problem by quitting MAMP, going to my Activity Monitor, killing an open mysqld process, then restarting MAMP. After that it worked fine. (Reviewing my error logs (MAMP/logs/) is what pointed me in that direction. Maybe the logs will help you, too).

Not sure if this will help, but that's what worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response jflores. I wasn't sure I would be getting any reply here and have learned to live with resetting MAMP every now and them. Ever since I switched to Firefox, it seldom crashes (it still does now and then). I will try your suggestions and see how it goes. Thanks again!